# TikZ: Page with several grids

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, grids, layers, pgflayers

I want to create a worksheet like that on a *DIN A4 paper* (21cm x 29.7cm):

[image]

The margins round about  should be something like 15mm (plusminus); the main thing is that I get as many grid-boxes as possible in the text area.

*How do I correctly set the page geometry and grid dimensions so that the two grids fits properly and are complete.*

I get so far only:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[showframe=true,
%includeheadfoot, 
%left=15mm, right=15mm, bottom=17mm, top=15mm
%textwidth=18cm, textheight=26cm,
width=18cm, height=26cm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, backgrounds}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
%ABC

\begin{tikzpicture}[shift={(current page.center)}, overlay,remember picture,
on background layer,
nodes={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
\node[draw, fill=white, anchor=north west, align=left, text width=18 cm, text height=6cm] at (-0.5\textwidth, 0.5\textheight) {Text:};
% Grids
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[red, step=2cm] (-0.5\textwidth, 0.5\textheight) grid +(\textwidth, -0.5\textheight);
\draw[red, step=1cm] (-0.5\textwidth, 0) grid +(\textwidth, -0.5\textheight);
\end{scope}

% Help
\node{x};
\draw[brown, thick] (0,0) -- (0.5\textwidth,0);
\draw[blue, thick] (0,0) -- (0,0.5\textheight);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please make a list of what is problematic ? I don't think the picture will be enough.

Comment: @BambOo  I added: "How do I correctly set the page geometry and grid dimensions so that the two grids fits properly and are complete?"

Answer (score 1):

I solved something like that, should be about 99%.

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[showframe=true,
%includeheadfoot, 
%left=15mm, right=15mm, bottom=17mm, top=15mm
%textwidth=18cm, textheight=26cm,
width=18cm, height=26cm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
%ABC
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style=red, shift={(current page.center)}, overlay,remember picture,
nodes={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
\node[anchor=north west, 
draw,
minimum width=1.0\textwidth,text width=1.0\textwidth-2mm,
minimum height=6cm,text depth=6cm-4mm,
align=left, 
] at (-0.5\textwidth, 0.5\textheight+0.7\baselineskip) (Textbox) {ABC};

% Grids:
\draw[step=1, dotted, help lines, shift={(Textbox.south west)}] (0,0) grid +(\textwidth,-4);
\draw[step=2, shift={(Textbox.south west)}] (0,0) coordinate(X) grid +(\textwidth,-8);

\draw[step=0.5, dotted, help lines, shift={($(Textbox.south west)+(0,-8)$)}] (0,0)  grid +(\textwidth,-4);
\draw[step=1, shift={($(Textbox.south west)+(0,-8)$)}] (0,0)  grid +(\textwidth,-12);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```